# Sql DB2 BETWEEN

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that has two columns that i am using to define my results.  One is a start date and one is a finish date. When doing a query i have used two different queries. One I have a clear understanding of:

```
   START DATE BETWEEN 2/1/2014 and 2/10/2014 
or FINISH DATE BETWEEN 2/1/2014 and 2/10/2014
```

but someone sent me the following and I can't quite grasp it. Is below the same as the one above? If so I am getting different results.

```
   2/1/2014 BETWEEN START DATE AND FINISH DATE
```

OR 2/10/2014 BETWEEN START DATE AND FINISH DATE.

I am a noob and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to forget that you're looking at SQL; imagine it's English (which it is, pretty much). If your start date is in January and your end date is in March, what would be the true statements in each case?

Comment: Not your actual problem, but [you should avoid the use of BETWEEN altogether](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (DB2 allows you to define the number of fractional seconds for timestamp types).  The same reasoning should also apply to all non-integral counts, so please, always explicitly qualify your ranges.

Comment: The two queries are different but we don't know what you are querying for so it could be that both are not what you want. I mean you could also try the `START_DATE < DATE('2014-02-10') AND DATE('2014-02-01') < FINISH_DATE` and that would be a 3rd query, different from both of yours. What are your requirements?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, I disagree. With the DATE datatype, between works perfectly fine. DB2 has always had DATE and MS SQL server finally got with the program.  Sure timestamps are a bit trickier. especially on MS SQL Server given the multiple types.  But I much prefer the clarity of intent that BETWEEN gives.

Comment: @Charles - the problem I have with `BETWEEN` is that it promotes thinking about natural ranges incorrectly - that there's such a thing as a distinct value.  Dates are a weird case where people have an idea that they're a distinct value, but reality is more complicated - you need more information for it to be actually useful (and too often a date column relies on meta knowledge - for instance, timezone).  It doesn't matter that it works - it's a style thing.  And depending on what `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` actually represent, they should maybe be timestamps anyways.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, but as long as you understand what a between statement means, what's the problem in using it?

Answer (score 1):

Queries are different.

First query your are looking for

`StartDate` to be between `'02/01/2014'` and `'02/10/2014'` `OR` 
`EndDate` to be between `'02/01/2014'` and `'02/10/2014'`

if one of two columns is between the dates those rows will be returned.

Second query you are looking for

`'02/01/2014'` to be between `StartDate` and `EndDate` `OR` 
`'02/10/2014'` to be between `StartDate` and `EndDate`

this will return different row set because you are only looking for records that happened during specific time frame. So all rows that `STARTED` on or before `'02/01/2014'` and ended on or after it will be returned or all rows that `STARTED` on or before `'02/10/2014'` and ended on or after it. This is really bad way to look at the data. You should just ignore the second query and stick with your first one.

Comment: This is `BETWEEN`, so "on or before" (or "on or after"), but yes.  I too would avoid the second version, especially as it's unlikely to be getting the correct range of values.